# How can I install the ltree extension (or any extension) from contrib when my postgres docker image is built?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile 

FROM postgres:13
COPY ./main-schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main-schema.sql
```

---

```
/* docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main-schema.sql */

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;

/* DOES NOT WORK */
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;

CREATE SCHEMA data_main;

SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', 'public', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

ALTER SCHEMA data_main OWNER TO default_admin;
ALTER ROLE default_admin SET search_path TO data_main;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;
```

I am able to create the data_main schema but I cannot install the LTREE extension.
LTREE is a module found in the contrib directory of the PostgreSQL distribution. In
order to install it I take the following steps:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
psql -Udefault_admin -dmain
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

This is fine, but I'd prefer to automate this. Why does the above script allow
me to create the schema, but not install an extension from contrib?

EDIT ====

There is no error message output during the build...just:

```
datamain-postgresql       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main-schema.sql
datamain-postgresql       | SET
datamain-postgresql       | SET
datamain-postgresql       | SET
datamain-postgresql       | SET    
datamain-postgresql       | SET
datamain-postgresql       | CREATE EXTENSION
datamain-postgresql       | CREATE SCHEMA
datamain-postgresql       | set_config
```

I have also noticed that if I open a shell and start the psql client I do see the extension. The LTREE datatype is not recognized until I do this:

```
DROP SCHEMA data_main CASCADE;
DROP EXTENSION ltree;
CREATE SCHEMA data_main;
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

if I try to create the extension before dropping, I get

```
ERROR:  extension "ltree" already exists
```

Without these steps I cannot run my migrations against this DB to create the tables depending on the LTREE datatype.

Comment: What is the error you see when you give `CREATE EXTENSION ltree;` inside your `main-schema.sql` file?

Comment: You know I should have mentioned that, let me add it.